# RDS copy across regions SQL Server snapshot

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to copy across different regions RDS snapshot of SQL Server 2012?

This is the error message in AWS console:

> Cross region snapshot copy is not supported for TDE encrypted snapshots (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDBSnapshotState; Request ID: )

The database and snapshot are not TDE encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RDS instance is multi-AZ, you won't be able to copy that snapshot across regions and unfortunately it gives the same error as if it were encrypted.  I opened a case with AWS support and got a helpful reply below.

> Please note the following from the 'Copying snapshots' RDS
>   documentation [1]:
>
> "You cannot copy a SQL Server DB snapshot across regions if the DB
>   snapshot was created from an instance using Multi-AZ mirroring."
>
> Due to this limitation, you will need to first disable the mirroring
>   option (Multi-AZ) for the source DB instance. You can then take a
>   snapshot and re-enable the mirroring option for the DB instance. You
>   would then be able to copy that snapshot to the desired region.  OR
>   The other work around is to restore the snapshot in same region in
>   Single AZ and then take a snapshot of that and try copy to the other
>   region.
>
> Sincere apologies for the confusion!
>
> ================================================
>
> Also on a side note, even if this DB instance did have the TDE option
>   enabled, you would still not be able to copy any snapshots taken from
>   it to another region. Please note the following from the same
>   documentation [1]:
>
> "You cannot copy a DB snapshot across regions if it was created from a
>   DB instance that is using Oracle Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) or
>   Microsoft SQL Server TDE."
>
> This is because the TDE encryption [2] is not the same as the
>   'encryption at rest' feature [3] that RDS provides which can be copied
>   cross regions.
>
> ================================================
>
> [1]
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html#USER_CopySnapshot.Limitations
>   [2]
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.TDE.html
>   [3]
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html

I did the second workaround of restoring the snapshot to a new instance in the same region, take a manual snapshot of it (can't use the automatic one), copy that snapshot to the new region, then delete the new/temporary instance.